# How to read my ROC curve UCI heart disease dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, roc

So I made a Random Forest model for the [UCI Heart Disease Dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+Disease), and I created the following ROC curve (after dichotomizing the data).

[image]

Forgive me, I am knew to machine learning. How do I read this curve? Is it a good curve?

Thanks!

Comment: In principle, ROC curves are for binary classification, while your dataset is a 5-class one; how exactly did you produce these curves? And what are the folds?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, but what I can tell is the folds are due to cross-validation, this line of code: cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6). The different lines are variances of the dataset.

Comment: As for the first question, I forgot to mention I modified the data to dichotomize it.